# Is it possible to develop a WPF based API application for a windows form made software?

Tags: wpf, winforms

### If a software is made in windows form, can it have an API application that has WPF interface?

Imagine a very old Software with an API that was created before WPF was born. If I develope an add-in using WPF is there any reason that it would not run properly inside that software?

Comment: What do you mean by "WPF based API application"?

Comment: An application made using e.g. WPF User Control Library template that has user control and wpf windows etc which uses Application Programming Interface of a software to do routine tasks in it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You just need to add the necessary framework references to your project.

Comment: @GlenThomas Then what makes an application not to support an api dll library made in wpf interface but support ones made by WinForms?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: @GlenThomas: Arent those framework references added once I create the project using the appropriate template?

Comment: Yes but if you want one project to support both WPF and WinForms there is not a template for that, so you will need to manually add whatever references are needed. Personally I would recommend creating separate projects for each, there is not really a need to combine them.

Comment: @GlenThomas is right. Our solution has 20 projects along with external server references. We are migrating it over to WPF. (It went from VB6 to WinForms before). The WinForms components are in a WinForms project, and the WPF ones are in WPF projects. The WinForms form instances do use WPF class instances.

Comment: @GlenThomas: Imagine a very old Software with an API that was created before WPF was born. If I develope an add-in using WPF is there any reason that it would not run properly inside that software?

Comment: So you are talking about creating a plug-in window for an existing WinForms application?

Comment: @GlenThomas: yes, exactly.

Comment: If the application is written in WinForms and was created "before WPF was born", then it is likely not possible as the application would need to reference WPF framework libraries and if hosting your WPF controls in WinForms windows it would also need to use a WPF element host control

Comment: @GlenThomas: and there is no workaround for that?

Comment: Are you able to modify the WinForms application's source code and rebuild it?

Comment: @GlenThomas: No, It is a commercial software.

Comment: Depending on what version of .NET it was built on, you _might_ be able to create a WinForms Window as a plugin and host a WPF UserControl inside it.

Comment: @GlenThomas: I would appreciate If you would post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application was build on a version of .NET that supports .NET, you *might* be able to create a WinForms Window as a plugin and host a WPF UserControl inside it.
It also depends entirely on how the developer of the application has created their plugin interface and what they support.